# .NET class documentation from within PowerShell?

Tags: .net, powershell

Is there a convenient method to access .NET class documentation (i.e. the MSDN documentation) from within PowerShel similar to "man 3" in UNIX shells?

Comment: @Ipthnc: what's that supposed to mean ? post an answer, not a comment...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the [Powershell Community Extensions 2.0](http://pscx.codeplex.com) (still only available via daily builds), we extend Get-Help to add a -object  parameter that, in conjunction with -online, will bring up MSDN documentation e.g.:

```
Get-Help -object (get-date) -online
```

Until we release a 2.0 beta (in a few weeks), grab the [module file from here](http://pscx.codeplex.com/sourcecontrol/changeset/view/62585?projectName=Pscx#1011400).  Note that it requires features in PowerShell 2.0.  Import this module like so:

```
Import-Module .\Pscx.GetHelp.psm1
```

Note that you can't use this on a namespace like System.Net but pick a type like System.Net.WebClient e.g.:

```
Get-Help -obj [System.Net.WebClient] -online
```

BTW, gives props to x0n (Oisin) for implementing this for PSCX.

Comment: You don't need the -online switch for stuff shipped with the  base framework itself (2.0 / 3.5) - I render help inline in the console for that, but of course -online might be newer.

-Oisin / x0n

Comment: Now it's 2020. It seems that this function has not been integrated into PowerShell. I went to Google to search for relevant keywords and found this article. Fortunately, this module is still being updated!

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by defining simple functions

```
function getDotNetHelp {
    param (
        $Object
    )
    Start-Process "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/$($Object.getType().FullName)?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0"
}
```

Executing the following command will directly open the. Net help document

```
getDotNetHelp ""
```

The page is as follows

[String Class (System) | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/System.String?view=net-5.0&viewFallbackFrom=powershellsdk-7.0.0)